# PyKrige constantly running into memory errors even with small dataset

Tags: python, interpolation, kriging

I have an xyz file in which I'd like to apply the interpolation method of `kriging` to via python.

In order to do this, I have come across the module `PyKrige` and duplicated this example perfectly on my own machine https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mZDVJ-RioBc4QHHpe2HBNJrx8sJ4-1Lw?pli=1#scrollTo=z0XaQWJq_gJ7

This gave me hope that the module could be easily implemented on my own data - sadly not.

My xyz file looks like so, and there are 36,000 sets of xyz points (973KB)

```
626814.86   233370.97   14.56
626814.43   233371.28   14.55
626814.01   233371.56   14.54
626813.57   233371.85   14.53
626813.10   233372.15   14.51
626812.66   233372.44   14.49
626812.23   233372.72   14.46
626811.78   233373.01   14.43
```

I have then altered the script from the example above to suit my data, by reading them into their 3 separate arrays and what not

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pylab import *

x1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test.xyz", usecols=0, dtype='float')
y1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test.xyz", usecols=1, dtype='float')
z1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test.xyz", usecols=2, dtype='float')

x = list(x1) #may not be a necessary step, but I added it so that after each x coordinate there was a comma like the examples array. Script wasn't working even before doing this
y = list(y1)
z = list(z1)


cax = plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, fraction=0.03)
plt.title('Test Points')


OK = OrdinaryKriging(
    x, 
    y, 
    z, 
    variogram_model='gaussian',
    verbose=True,
    enable_plotting=False,
    nlags=5,
)

OK.variogram_model_parameters

gridx = np.arange(626000, 629094, 5, dtype='float64')
gridy = np.arange(231500, 234500, 5, dtype='float64')
zstar, ss = OK.execute("grid", gridx, gridy)

print(zstar.shape)
print(ss.shape)

cax = plt.imshow(zstar, extent=(626000, 629094, 231500, 234500), origin='lower')
plt.scatter(x, y, c='z', marker='.')
cbar=plt.colorbar(cax)
plt.title('Test')
savefig( 'C:/users/public/test.png' )
print('image saved')
```

My issue is that it gets to the execution of the Ordinary Kriging and then complains

```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.2 GiB for an array with shape (36936, 36936) and data type float64
```

Understandably, I thought that the issue was the 36,000 points being too many. So, I decided to try a smaller snippet of the data. Now when I say smaller, I mean **20** points (1KB!!!). THE SAME ERROR!!!!

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Realistically, I only want the interpolated PNG, not the points and scatterplot

Answer (score 1):

Fix this line `gridx = np.arange(62600, 629094, 5, dtype='float64')`

You're missing a digit in the start parameter - "`62600`", should have 6 digits eg "`626000`". So your current script is trying to interpolate onto a very large array.

Comment: oh yes I see that now. Howvever, even with that fixed I'm still getting the error ```numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.2 GiB for an array with shape (36936, 36936) and data type float64```

Comment: Works for me with your code and those example points. It only blows out the memory with `gridx = np.arange(62600, 629094, 5, dtype='float64')`

Comment: Yes I got it working for the 8 points, but the full 36,000-point dataset is proving to be an issue

Comment: you can try with  `dtype="float32"` if you are sure you don't need the float64 precision otherwise you might have to do it in batches

Comment: @LouisCottereau Realistically, I only want the raster image from the background. I don't even need the scattergraph/plots - so I'm wondering would it help if I were to try and remove them

Comment: @hi2938021 kriging is really memory intensive, by modifying the step to 500 (a 100 times less steps) in both grid axis `np.arange(a,b, 500)` the process peaked at 30 GB of ram so imagine with 100*100 = 10 000 times more steps in your ranges , your kriging had no real chance of finishing. Its highly dependant on the number of grid steps and the number of points you need to reduce one or the other or both and you procress will manage to finish

Comment: @LouisCottereau ah okay! In all honesty, I wasn't sure what the step was actually for. However, I'll try increasing to 500 like you've suggested and see if I can get it to complete - thanks!

Comment: @hi2938021 You will however lose in resolution since each grid step will be bigger. The bigger the step the less squares you will have in your output

Comment: @LouisCottereau yes I had thought this the case. However, I need all 36,000 points, so will have to try the increase in step rather than splitting the dataset up. Very frustrating, as I can run the Kriging function in ArcGIS Pro with a cell size of 0.5 on this same dataset, and be fully interpolated within 45 minutes. Sadly, the work I'm working on requires an open-source python script :(